# Problemas para ejecutar eventos en una funcion de conversion JS

Tags: javascript, funciones, eventos

me estoy iniciando en la programación de javascrip y me han dado un ejercicio de conversión en este caso es solo usando 2 opciones de cambio, y la idea es que se pueda hacer a la viceversa. He recorrido todo el stack tanto en español como inglés para ver si habia una pregunta similar pero los ejemplos que habian no me han servido o no he sabido como aplicarlo.

Errores que de los que estoy conciente: llamado de los documents y las propiedades de innerHTLM, el onclick de button tambien me da null.

Hasta ahora esto es lo que tengo:

Html

```
<div class="container">
        <header>Convertidor</header>
        <form action="#">
            <div class="amount-box">
                <p>Ingresar monto</p>
                <input type="text" value="1" id="amount">
            </div>
            <div class="options">
                <!--Desde-->
                <div class="from-box">
                    <p>De</p>
                    <div class="select-box">
                        <select id="from" onchange="convert()">
                            <option value="1">USD</option>
                            <option value="2">ARS</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="img">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </div>
                <!--a-->
                <div class="to-box">
                    <p>A</p>
                    <div class="select-box">
                        <select id="to" onchange="convert()">
                            <option value="2">ARS</option>
                            <option value="1">USD</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!---->
            </div>
            <span class="exc-ra"></span>
            <button onclick="convert()">Convertir</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

JS

```
function convert() {
    let amount = parseInt(document.getElementById("amount")).value;

    let from = document.getElementById("from").value;
    let to = document.getElementById("to").value;

    const usd = 1;
    const ars = 300;
    let result = 0;

    if (from === 1 && to === 2) {
        result = amount * usd; 
    } else if (from === 2 && to === 1) {
        result = amount / ars;
    } else {
        result = amount;
    }
    document.getElementById("exc-ra").innerHTML = '$' + result;
}
```

Comment: Hola Melisa, fijate que en **`let amount = parseInt( document.getElementById( "amount" )).value;`** el paréntesis debe ir después del `value` osea **`let amount = parseInt( document.getElementById( "amount" ).value );`**, ya que estás parseando lo que devuelve `value`.

Comment: Lo hice, y tambien corregí id de span que no lo tenía, ahora me muestra el valor, pero no aplica la funcion, osea no me da la conversion :(

Comment: Hola Melisa, considera revisar por favor [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice algunos cambios para que funcionara...

```js
function convert() {
      // como te decía en los comentarios, el paréntesis va
      // después de "value", y tambien convertí los retornos 
      // de "to" y "from".  
    let amount = parseInt( document.getElementById( "amount" ).value );

    let from = parseInt( document.getElementById( "from" ).value );
    let to = parseInt( document.getElementById( "to" ).value );

    const ars = 300;
    let result = 0;

    if ( from === 1 && to === 2 ) {
          // acá cambié amount * usd
        result = amount * ars; 
    } 
    else if ( from === 2 && to === 1 ) {
        result = amount / ars;
    } 
    else {
        result = amount;
    }
    document.getElementById( "exc-ra" ).innerHTML = '$' + result;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header> Convertidor </header>
    <form action="#">
        <div class="amount-box">
            <p> Ingresar monto </p>
            <input type="text" value="1" id="amount">
        </div>
        <div class="options">
            <!--Desde-->
            <div class="from-box">
                <p> De </p>
                <div class="select-box">
                    <select id="from" onchange="convert()">
                        <option value="1"> USD </option>
                        <option value="2"> ARS </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"> </i>
            </div>
            <!--a-->
            <div class="to-box">
                <p> A </p>
                <div class="select-box">
                    <select id="to" onchange="convert()">
                        <option value="2"> ARS </option>
                        <option value="1"> USD </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!---->
        </div>
            <!-- cambié class="exc-ra" por id="exc-ra" ya que en -->
            <!-- la función "convert", usas "getElementById". -->
        <span id="exc-ra"> </span>

          <!-- agregué el "type", ya que al darle "click", --> 
          <!-- después de un segundo... desaparecia todo!. -->
        <button type="button" onclick="convert()"> Convertir </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Con estás mínimas correcciones, el código funciona... el principal problema, era que convertías a entero el contenido de `amount` y los de `from` y `to` no, entonces al comparar con `===` daba siempre false (`===` compara el valor y el tipo), era válido no convertir ninguno o convertir todos y usar `===`, o convertir unos si y otros no pero usar `==` , pero bueno, son cosas que nos pasan a todos, por otro lado, en el `if`, multiplicabas `amount` por `usd` que vale "`1`"... por lo que la desaparecí.

Comment: Dios, muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme! de la forma que lo hiciste ahora entiendo mas los pasos y los eventos. :)

Comment: Un placer poder ayudarte!!!.

Comment: @MelisaAhumada Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos!!